# How to set name which is unique for a component based on their properties?

Tags: java, swing, testing, automation, awt

I want to differentiate each component in my application uniquely. How can I prepare an unique name with its properties so that I can set this name? In my testing tool I have to perform actions on the correct component.

I tried name preparing like:

```
String parentName = component.getParent();
String xpoint = component.getX();
String ypoint = component.getY();
component.setName(parentName_xpoint_ypoint);
```

Can you tell me if whatever I tried will give the unique component if I call using
`component.getName().equals(parentName_xpoint_ypoint)`?

Comment: Do you actually care about the contents of the name? What about something like `UUID#randomUUID`?

Comment: can you explain what UUID#randomUUID means?

Comment: [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) is a universally unique identifier. if you convert it to a string it'll just look like a random hex string - its value is meaningless, but it will definitely be unique.

Comment: UUID.randomUUID() gets unique indetifier, agreed ,but it is not always same for a component.If i set this value for a component with setName(..), second time while testing with what i can compare and decide that this is the actual component??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the name (whether it is human readable or not) you could instead use/generate the hashcode based on the properties of the class. The hashcode will be different when X/Y are changed since the name is based on it.
Within the following page [Implementing hashCode](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28) you see a nice example on how you can generate hashcode based on the properties of a class using a util class.